# Return the key from a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using PHP I can return the key by looking up the value inside an array.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'fruit1' => 'apple',
    'fruit2' => 'orange',
    'fruit3' => 'grape',
    'fruit4' => 'apple',
    'fruit5' => 'apple');


while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
    if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}

?>
```

But I'm learning javascript, I've searched and haven't found a solution, I'm still a beginner.

How can I return the key by fetching the value within a given array?

I've already tried using its functions: .indexOf() or .findIndex()

```
var array = [];
array['key'] = 'Value';
array['car'] = 'Ferrari';
array['car2'] = 'BMW';
console.log(key='Ferrari'??);
```

How to Return 'car' if Value = 'Ferrari' ?

another doubt in this case is it better to use Array or Class? Is it possible to return the class key?

```
var pessoas = {'car': 'Ferrari', 'car2':'BMW'};
```

Comment: Even though an array is an object, the arrays are special. According to your example, what you're referring to is a key-value object.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys, only numeric indexes. When you pass a string to an Array, you are actually creating a new property for the Array object, not a new item in the Array data. If you need keys, use an `object`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use Objects instead of arrays in `JavaScript` to store `PHP` equivalent of arrays with keys. In JS if you make an array, add non numeric keys to it and then do .length it will give 0. So many built in functions do not work, like `.filter` `.find` and `.map`.

```js
//your way
let pessoas  = [];
pessoas ["car1"] = "Ferrari";
pessoas ["car2"] = "BMW";
//the safe way. Both ways work.
pessoas = {'car': 'Ferrari', 'car2':'BMW'};
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
}


console.log(getObjKey(pessoas, 'BMW'));
```

Additionally, you can turn string-keyed arrays into object like this:

```js
 
    function getObjKey(obj, value) {
        return Object.keys(obj).find(key=>obj[key] === value);
    }
    var arrayToObject = (array)=>Object.keys(array).reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr] = array[curr],
    acc), {});

    let pessoas = [];
    pessoas["car1"] = "Ferrari";
    pessoas["car2"] = "BMW";
    pessoas.push("corretArray");
    pessoas = arrayToObject(pessoas);
    console.log(getObjKey(pessoas, 'BMW'));
```

Comment: @Ele In general it's bad practice to keep strings in array. On your example above do `array.length` and it will tell you 0 even if you have 'elements' on it. read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/practical-javascript-arrays-vs-objects-3c1f895907bd)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Doger the OP's code does not produce elements with the array data (which is why the length is 0). It creates new properties on the Array instance.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't have keys, only numeric indexes. When you pass a string to an Array, you are actually creating a new property for the Array object, not a new item in the Array data (for example, `.length` is a property of an Array, not an indexed value).

```js
var array = [];
// The following 3 lines don't create indexed values in the array:
array['key'] = 'Value';
array['car'] = 'Ferrari';
array['car2'] = 'BMW';

// Which is proven here:
console.log(array.length);  // 0

// What they do is create new properties on the Array instance:
console.log(array.car2); // "BMW"
```

If you need keys, use an `object`, which is structured as follows:

```
 {key: keyValue, key: keyValue, key:keyValue ...}
```

where the key is always a string, so quotes around the key name are not necessary.

```js
var pessoas = {car: 'Ferrari', car2:'BMW'};

console.log("The second car is: " + pessoas.car2);

console.log("The keys and key names are: ");
for (var prop in pessoas){
  console.log(prop + " : " + pessoas[prop]);
}
```

Comment: I understand, but in this example it does not return the key.

Comment: @KleutonNovais The key name itself can easily be returned. Let me update the answer.